# problem in videos

Tags: video, vlc, banshee, media

When ever I tried to use banshee software, the following message appear:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I do try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove
```

As I saw in previous questions answered here, but nothing seems to work.
So Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just do the steps on this answer: [Ubuntu 14.04, problem when install gstreamer1.0-libav, unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-with-gstreamer1-0-libav/560934#560934) & it solve the problem after I use:

sudo apt-get autoremove

many thanks for the efforts muzaffar.