# Xfce 4.12 + KWin5

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, kwin

I installed Xubuntu 15.04 with Xfce 4.12.

I would like to use KWin as the window manager.

With previous versions of Xfce and KWin replacing xfwm with kwin was pretty straightforward, but now both Xfce and Kwin seem to have changed significantly and old instructions (see for instance: [here](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/tutorial-how-to-use-kwin-window-manager-with-xfce)) are not valid anymore.

**Additional notes**:

1. With in KWin5, the program `kwin` has been replaced by `kwin_x11` and `kwin_wayland`.
2. If I run `kwin_x11 --replace`, I get no decorations.
3. If I try to install `kwin-style-qtcurve` (as indicated [here](https://youtu.be/z5kiYjg3Rog) for an older Xfce), I get a dependency problem on `libkdecorations4abi2`:

   ```
   $ sudo env LANG=en_US apt-get install kwin-style-qtcurve
   ...
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    kwin-style-qtcurve : Depends: libkdecorations4abi2 (>= 4:4.11.1) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: kde-style-qtcurve but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

Comment: No, it doesn't work either way. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Try install it using `aptitude` similar steps to [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-when-install-gstreamer1-0-libav-unmet-dependencies/568417#568417) . It will show multiple solutions.

Comment: As per the Xubuntu Strategy Document, dumping xfwm for kwin as your window manager means you've stripped a critical core component out.  By that definition you are no longer running Xubuntu as its developers define it.