# libavcodec-extra-54 and libavformat54 not upgrading

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, xubuntu

Each time I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the this output:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libavcodec-extra-54 libavformat54
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Is there a way to force the upgrade or should I just purge them with all of their dependencies and reinstall the packages in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/502208/15003, `sudo apt-get install libopus0` followed by `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav` should upgrade the packages that are held back.

Comment: No that does not work. Here is the output: `The following packages have been kept back:
  libavformat54
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`

Comment: @EmilZahariev How about `sudo apt install libavformat54`?

Comment: Here is the output of that: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavformat54 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: And here is what happens when I try to install those packages: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-extra-54 : Conflicts: libavcodec54 but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
 libavcodec54 : Depends: libx264-123 but it is not installable
                Conflicts: libavcodec-extra-54 but 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2279609 seems to suggest that `gstreamer1.0-libav` could be what you are missing. As the forum post suggests, can you post the output of `sudo apt-cache policy gstreamer1.0-libav`?

Comment: Here is the output: `gstreamer1.0-libav:
  Installed: 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.3-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages`

Comment: No that still gets me the same output as before when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and I dont have VLC

Comment: I explored a little and found this: http://askubuntu.com/a/502208/15003. Looks like it works but the OP wasn't sure why. You could try this and see if it works. Then undo the install if you are not comfortable with the fix.

Comment: That one worked. Might want to edit your answer with the link.

Comment: @EmilZahariev Nice, will do.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade them manually

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra-54 libavformat54
```