# gstreamer dependencies problem

Tags: 14.04, package-management, xubuntu, dependencies

When I try and install gstreamer I get dependency errors. I already followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502207/ubuntu-14-04-problem-when-install-gstreamer1-0-libav-unmet-dependencies) thread and it did not work. Here is the error output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-libav: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 7:1.2.5-1~trusty1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.8 is to be installed
                    Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.8 is to be installed
                          Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
                          Depends: libdvdnav4 (>= 4.1.3) but 5.0.3-1~trusty is to be installed
                          Depends: libdvdread4 (>= 4.1.3) but 5.0.3-1~trusty is to be installed
                          Depends: libegl1-x11 but it is a virtual package
                          Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgles2 but it is a virtual package
                          Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.17-0) but 2.12.23-12ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1) but 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 146) but 1:204-5ubuntu20.19 is to be installed
                          Depends: libmpg123-0 (>= 1.6.2) but 1.16.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libopenal1 (>= 1:1.13) but 1:1.14-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.18) but 1:0.4.18-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.36) but 2.40.2-1 is to be installed
                          Depends: librtmp0 (>= 2.3) but 2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1 is to be installed
                          Depends: libsoundtouch0 (>= 1.7.1-3~) but 1.7.1-5 is to be installed
                          Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
                          Depends: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8) but 2:1.0.17-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                          Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.7.4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.7 is to be installed
                          Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers (= 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1) but 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1 is to be installed
                          Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad (= 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1) but 1.2.4-1~ubuntu1 is to be installed
```